# Why »einen« in the sentence »Ich nehme einen Kaffee«?

Tags: article

I like to know why *einen* is used in the sentence

> Ich nehme einen Kaffee

instead of »ein«. Kaffee is masculine. I cannot reason why the word is accusative not nominative.

Can anyone here explain me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your native language? What languages other than that do you have solid knowledge of?

Comment: My native language is Tamil but I have a solid knowledge of English.

Answer (score 4):

"einen Kaffee" is the accusative case object (ich nehme *wen oder was*?). The subject in nominative case is "Ich".

Comment: What is accusative case object? How can I identify accusative object in a sentence?

Comment: German has different object cases in contrast to English. Which one you use in a specific case depends on the verb. Nominative case is for the subject.

Answer (score 2):

Ein (Nominativ)
Eines (Genitiv)
Einem (Dativ)
**Einen (Akkusativ)**

*Kaffee* here is an object therefore *Akkusativ* applies.